#  error OPENing an OUT SYS_REFCURSOR with FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, sys-refcursor, ora-03113

I'm calling a procedure (from C# via ODP.Net with Oracle.DataAccess.dll 4.112.3.0 to OracleDB 11.2.0.1 with some patches) that has an `OUT SYS_REFCURSOR` (let's call it `pCursorOut`).  In the procedure, I do this:

```
OPEN pCursorOut FOR SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

My C# code:

```
var oracleDataReader = oracleCommand.ExecuteDataReader();
dataTable.Load(oracleDataReader);
```

Calling `Load()` results in an `OracleException`:

> ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

If I remove the `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`, it works correctly (other than *not* locking the records, which I need).

Could this be a version conflict?

How can this be solved?

**UPDATE:** I suspect this may be because I'm trying to lock more than one record at a time with the table load.  I'm doing some additional testing on this now...   NOPE.  That's not it.  Doing a `yield return` on a `while (oracleDataReader.Read())` throws the same thing on the first `.Read()` call.

Comment: Check the server. There may be a corresponding `ORA-00600` that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a versioning conflict.  I upgraded to OracleDB 11.2.0.3, and it started working as expected.